# ClassNotFoundException error while interacting with database

Tags: java, database, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to run a mapreduce program which runs on top of an underlying database.        When I installed a distribution of hadoop which is available in hadoop downloads. The programs worked fine for this distribution. But when I compiled my own distribution of hadoop and tried to run the same programs I am getting the below error. I followed the procedures like putting the mysql connector jar in the hadoop/lib directory and putting one in the distributed cache. While these procedures worked for the distribution which was available under hadoop downloads but they did not work for the distribution which I created.
Can anyone kindly tell what might have gone wrong ? I tried all other ways like updating classpath and HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable but none worked.

```
hduser@ramanujan:~$ hadoop jar SimpleConn.jar 
13/04/15 13:50:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/04/15 13:50:17 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
13/04/15 13:50:17 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
13/04/15 13:50:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1366013851608_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1236)
    at DBCountPageView.run(DBCountPageView.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at DBCountPageView.main(DBCountPageView.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:163)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:189)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

Use the following to add all the jar dependencies from current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.

Comment: If it worked can you please mark this as the answer so the question gets closed off properly?